# How to break a text block up so that it will display only One Word on each line

Tags: text, visual-studio-2012, ms-word

I am importing longer form text into a Unity program. I need one word of the longer text to be displayed on each line...
Thanks

Comment: What language are you trying to use? Java?

Comment: @Brandon Doesn't really matter, if the workflow is simple. I have to have the output in a .txt file in Unity3D. If I can run from a browser / Word / Visual Studio easily.. Thanks!

Comment: @Bentoon What is the maximum permissible line length?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with working with large blocks of text in Word is that operations like Find and Replace can only be performed with Find text strings of 255 characters or less without causing an error. Once you import your text and assign it to a string variable, you can use Len() to determine the length of the string and then use Left() Mid() and Right() to breakup the larger string into shorter chunks of 250 characters each. Here's some code I wrote for just a find and replace situation:

```
With Selection.Find
    y = Len(Selection.Text)
    Select Case y          
        Case Is <= 250
            x = 1
            .Text = stFound
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll    
         Case Is <= 500
             Dim stFound2 As String      
              x = 2
              z = Len(stFound) - 250
              stFound1 = Left(stFound, 250)
              stFound2 = Right(stFound, z)
         Case Is <= 750
              Dim stFound2 As String
              Dim stFound3 As String
              x = 3
              stFound1 = Left(stFound, 250)
              stFound2 = Mid(stFound, 251, 249)
              stFound3 = Right(stFound, Len(stFound) - 500)
    End Select
End With
```

I then used a For Next loop to run a Find and Replace on each string.

In your situation, it's going to be important to not break up the strings in the middle of a word. To do this you can use the InStr() function to find the position of spaces within your string and then break up the text according to where the spaces are. I wouldn't try using the Split() function on the raw text as depending on the size of the string you could run into a Subscript Out of Range error.

Once the text is chunked down into useable pieces, use the Split() function to send each word to an array and then run the following code to put each word on it's own line or paragraph:

```
Dim stTxt as String
dim stWord as String
dim stArr() as String
dim x as long
stTxt = 'One of your text strings

stArr() = Split(stTxt)

For x = LBound(stArr()) to UBound(stArr())
    stWord = stArr(x) & "^p"
    Selection.Typetext stWord
Next
```

Comment: «The problem with working with large blocks of text in Word is that operations can only be performed on text strings shorter than 255 characters without causing an error» Strictly speaking, that's not true. A *wildcard* Find with ^13[!^13]@^13, for example, will find a paragraph break, followed by other content, then another paragraph break, of 500 *words* or more (i.e. well over 3,000 characters).

Comment: And if you separated those chunks of 500 words or more into strings and tried to do something like a Find and Replace operation, you would get a Subscript Out of Range Error.

Comment: You really should take more time to understand how Word works. A Find/Replace can be done on that range too - you just have to know what you're doing and keep the Find *expression* (not the find *range*) under 256 characters.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what I was saying, and basically agreeing with me. The string text or string variable holding the text being searched for must be 255 characters or less. I never said this applied to the range being searched. What I did say is that if the string being used as the Find term is > 255 characters, executing a Find and Replace will return an error of Subscript Out of Range.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research, I determined that the 255 character limit to text strings only affects some functions, not all. So I took a 17,335 character (including spaces) Word document and ran Split() on it to create an Array. There were no errors and the resulting array had a UBound of 2690.

So the next question is what kind of text is being imported into Word and what size is it. Is it just a list of words separated by spaces, or another delimiter? Does it contain any punctuation? If it's just a list of words separated by spaces or another delimiter such as a comma or semicolon, the Split() function will sort the words into an Array, at least up to 17,000 characters. More testing would be required for a larger text block. If the text contains punctuation, you would have to process the text to remove the unwanted punctuation which can be done with a Wildcard Find and Replace as long as the Find string is <= 255 characters. But if all you have are words and spaces or some other delimiter, using Split() to separate each word into an array element would work and then just run code as in the second half of my previous example:

```
For x = LBound(stArr()) to UBound(stArr())
    stWord = stArr(x) & "^p"
    Selection.Typetext stWord
Next
```